# How do I reference the URL in my functions when they are displayed differently in my datasources?

Tags: google-sheets

The below are the same URLs but are displayed this way across different tabs/datasources.

- https://info.example.com/page1/
- info.example.com/page1/
- /page1/

For example, CELL J1 has the following formula

```
={"Sessions";ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="","",VLOOKUP("*"&B2:B,GA!$A$8:$J,4,FALSE)))}
```

This formuala is trying to look up the URLs in column B with the URLs in the GA tab under Column A.

The difference is that the URLs are the same but are collected differently.

How do I build the URL into my functions to not have to create new columns to strip the URLs?

Example Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHkU-rNtNhoOKvW_CWY7WU5OLsMFVqEFNRZlx_R-7RY

Comment: question is incomprehensible. in which cell you need formula and what that formula should do exactly?

Comment: Hi @player0 thank you for your reply. I went ahead and added more context to the description. Please let me know if this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and extract the common string in your URLs and use it in your VLOOKUP.

In your example, the common string is `/page1/`

- https://info.example.com/page1/
- info.example.com/page1/
- /page1/

You can use `REGEXEXTRACT` to extract the string after `https://info.example.com`

**Try this:**

```
={"Sessions";ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="","",VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"/[^.*]+$"), "/"),GA!$A$8:$J,4,FALSE)))}
```

Regex `"/[^.*]+$"` will get the character from the last slash up to the last character in the string.

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en)

Comment: This works for sources that reference the slug (i.e. /page1/) but what if the source has the following URL info.example.com/page1/? The landing page on the aggregate view is stripped down with this formula but the comparison for column J has a more complete URL.

Comment: Are you able to look at column F of the spreadsheet above and help sort out the regex for this URL?

Comment: @MegaMikeJr - Apologies, I might confused you on my statement above. I edited my answer. `"/[^.*]+$"` regex will get the character from the last slash up to the last character in the string.

Comment: @MegaMikeJr - I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is a new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question by including the detailed information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it.

Answer (score 0):

either:

```
=INDEX({"Sessions"; IF(B2:B="",, VLOOKUP(IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "/[^.*]+$"), "/"), GA!A8:J, 4, ))})
```

or:

```
=INDEX({"Sessions"; IF(B2:B="",, VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
 {"https://info.example.com"&GA!A8:A, GA!B8:J}, 4, ))})
```

[image]